# How to extend Lory.js navigation dots to all list itmes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently my lory slider dots navigation only seem to work for the first four then stops.

Code [here](https://codepen.io/goldman/pen/PmKzEY)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var simple_dots       = document.querySelector('.js_simple_dots');
        var dot_count         = simple_dots.querySelectorAll('.js_slide').length;
        var dot_container     = simple_dots.querySelector('.js_dots');
        var dot_list_item     = document.createElement('li');

        function handleDotEvent(e) {
            if (e.type === 'before.lory.init') {
              for (var i = 0, len = dot_count; i < len; i++) {
                var clone = dot_list_item.cloneNode();
                dot_container.appendChild(clone);
              }
              dot_container.childNodes[0].classList.add('active');
            }
            if (e.type === 'after.lory.init') {
              for (var i = 0, len = dot_count; i < len; i++) {
                dot_container.childNodes[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                  dot_navigation_slider.slideTo(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(dot_container.childNodes, e.target));
                });
              }
            }
            if (e.type === 'after.lory.slide') {
              for (var i = 0, len = dot_container.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
                dot_container.childNodes[i].classList.remove('active');
              }
              dot_container.childNodes[e.detail.currentSlide - 1].classList.add('active');
            }
            if (e.type === 'on.lory.resize') {
                for (var i = 0, len = dot_container.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
                    dot_container.childNodes[i].classList.remove('active');
                }
                dot_container.childNodes[0].classList.add('active');
            }
        }
        simple_dots.addEventListener('before.lory.init', handleDotEvent);
        simple_dots.addEventListener('after.lory.init', handleDotEvent);
        simple_dots.addEventListener('after.lory.slide', handleDotEvent);
        simple_dots.addEventListener('on.lory.resize', handleDotEvent);

        var dot_navigation_slider = lory(simple_dots, {
            infinite: 1,
            enableMouseEvents: true,
             slidesToScroll: 1,
            rewind: true
        });
    });
```

```css
/* FP FAQS SLIDER */
.frontpage-section--faqs {
    background-color: light-blue;
    min-height: 365px;
    padding: 100px 0px 125px;

    .frame {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 0;
      line-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      max-width: 1100px;
      margin: auto;

      .slides {
          display: block;
      }
    }
    .faqs-slider {
      .prev, .next {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 10px 18px 5px;
        background: green;
                  top: 185px;
          margin-top: 0px;

        @media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
          top: 50%;
                  margin-top: -25px;

        }
      }
      .next {
        right: 0;
      }
      .prev {
        left: 0;
        &:hover .vertical-txt, &:focus .vertical-txt{
        display: none;
        }

      }
      .next svg, .prev svg {
        width: 25px;
      }
      // DOT NAVIGATION
      .js_dots.dots {
       margin: 0; 
       padding: 0; 
       text-align: center; 
       margin-top: 55px; 
       position: absolute; 
       width: 100%; 
       
       li {
         border: 1px solid black;
         border-radius: 5px; 
         display: inline-block;
         height: 10px;
         width: 10px;
         margin: 0 5px;
       }
       li.active {
         background-color: red ; 
       }
       
      }
    }
    .faqs-slide {
        width: 285px;
        margin: 0px 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: normal;
        line-height: 1.2;
    }
    .faqs-slide__text {
          padding-left: 30px;
              min-height: 225px;
        @media only screen and (min-width: 940px) {
          max-width: 620px;
          float: right;
        }
    }
    .faqs-slide__name {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: red;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .faqs-slide__description {
        font-size: 16px;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
    .faqs__symbol{
        position: absolute;
        left: -30px;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: light-green; 
    }
    .faqs__symbol--teal{
        color: green; 
    }
    .faqs-label.vertical-txt{
      left: 0;
      top: 100px;
      z-index: 999;
      color: white;
      background-color: green;
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      font-size: 35px;
        @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
          display: none;
        }      
      font-weight: 400;
      &:hover, &:focus{
        display: none;
      }

    }

}



.vertical-txt{
  text-align:right;
  color:black;
    height:2.5em;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display:block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transform-origin:top left; /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -webkit-transform-origin:top left; /* Safari and Chrome */
  moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform-origin:top left; /* Firefox */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
  -o-transform-origin:top left; /* Opera */
}
```

```html
<section class="frontpage-section frontpage-section--faqs" id="faqs">
  <div class="faqs-slider slider js_simple_dots simple" data-rellax-speed="2" data-rellax-percentage="1" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <div class="frame js_frame">
      <ul class="slides js_slides" data-right-height="" style="transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate3d(-330px, 0px, 0px);"><li class="faqs-slide js_slide" data-right-height-content="" style="height: 344px;">
          <div class="faqs-slide__text">
            <div class="faqs-slide__name">
              <span class="faqs__symbol">Q
              </span>
when an unknown printer took a galley o            </div>
            <div class="faqs-slide__description">
              <span class="faqs__symbol faqs__symbol--teal">A
              </span>
       <p>1Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
                                      <li class="faqs-slide js_slide active" data-right-height-content="" style="height: 344px;">
          <div class="faqs-slide__text">
            <div class="faqs-slide__name">
              <span class="faqs__symbol">Q
              </span>
Who’s eligible to become a werweq host?            </div>
            <div class="faqs-slide__description">
              <span class="faqs__symbol faqs__symbol--teal">A
              </span>
       <p>2Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          
            </div>
          </div>
        </li> 
                      <li class="faqs-slide js_slide" data-right-height-content="" style="height: 344px;">
          <div class="faqs-slide__text">
            <div class="faqs-slide__name">
              <span class="faqs__symbol">Q
              </span>
You must be a Birth ewrrwerw alumni simply            </div>
            <div class="faqs-slide__description">
              <span class="faqs__symbol faqs__symbol--teal">A
              </span>
       <p>3Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          
            </div>
          </div>
        </li> 
                      <li class="faqs-slide js_slide" data-right-height-content="" style="height: 344px;">
          <div class="faqs-slide__text">
            <div class="faqs-slide__name">
              <span class="faqs__symbol">Q
              </span>
when an unknow?            </div>
            <div class="faqs-slide__description">
              <span class="faqs__symbol faqs__symbol--teal">A
              </span>
       <p>4Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          
            </div>
          </div>
        </li> 
                      <li class="faqs-slide js_slide" data-right-height-content="" style="height: 344px;">
          <div class="faqs-slide__text">
            <div class="faqs-slide__name">
              <span class="faqs__symbol">Q
              </span>
book. It has survived not only five centuries, but            </div>
            <div class="faqs-slide__description">
              <span class="faqs__symbol faqs__symbol--teal">A
              </span>
       <p>5Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          
            </div>
          </div>
        </li> 
                      <li class="faqs-slide js_slide" data-right-height-content="" style="height: 344px;">
          <div class="faqs-slide__text">
            <div class="faqs-slide__name">
              <span class="faqs__symbol">Q
              </span>
when an unknown printer took a galley o            </div>
            <div class="faqs-slide__description">
              <span class="faqs__symbol faqs__symbol--teal">A
              </span>
       <p>6Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          
            </div>
          </div>
        </li> 
                <li class="faqs-slide js_slide" data-right-height-content="" style="height: 344px;">
          <div class="faqs-slide__text">
            <div class="faqs-slide__name">
              <span class="faqs__symbol">Q
              </span>
Who’s eligible to become a weqtt host?            </div>
            <div class="faqs-slide__description">
              <span class="faqs__symbol faqs__symbol--teal">A
              </span>
       <p>7Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          
            </div>
          </div>
        </li></ul>
    </div>
    <span class="js_prev prev">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 501.5 501.5">
        <g>
          <path fill="#ffffff" d="M302.67 90.877l55.77 55.508L254.575 250.75 358.44 355.116l-55.77 55.506L143.56 250.75z">
          </path>
        </g>
      </svg>
          <span class="faqs-label vertical-txt">Faq's</span>
    </span>
    <span class="js_next next">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 501.5 501.5">
        <g>
          <path fill="#ffffff" d="M199.33 410.622l-55.77-55.508L247.425 250.75 143.56 146.384l55.77-55.507L358.44 250.75z">
          </path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <ul class="js_dots dots"><li class="active"></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>
  </div>
</section>
```